# WiFi turns off by itself

Tags: wi-fi, 4.3-jelly-bean

Whenever I connect to a network, my phone (Galaxy Note II running Jellybean 4.3) connects and establishes a solid connection, but then turns off the WiFi just seconds later. Restarting my phone hasn't worked and I'm not yet willing to do a factory reset unless its the only foreseeable solution to this problem.